# Extract section of file to a variable, from within a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, perl, command-line, sed

I'm writing a script intended to run under bash in OS X. I have Markdown files that look like this:

```
# File name

## Heading 1

Some text


## Heading 2

* List item 1
* List item 2


## Some other section
...
```

I'm trying to read everything inside `Heading 2` into a variable, and I've tried using `sed`, `grep`, and `perl`, but can't get a working solution. Of those tools, it looked to (in theory) be possible and easiest with Perl, especially given that I need multiple lines. It looks like this regex works (at least with javascript syntax):

```
## Heading 2\s+(.+)\s+
```

I'd like to keep it a one-liner, and stick to only tools available on stock OS X (El Capitan, 10.11). Assume I only know "Heading 2" up front, not the following header caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sed :

```
$ myvar=$(sed "/^## $1$/,/^## Heading/!d;//d;/^$/d" file)
$ echo "$myvar"
* List item 1
* List item 2
```

You can remove `/^$/d` if you want to preserve blank lines.

**Update :**

I've replaced single quotes with double quotes to allow shell expansion.

You can call it with `./scriptname.sh "Heading 2"`.

Some explanations :

- `/^## $1$/,/^## Heading/` applies subsequent commands to lines matching the first pattern up to next line containing the second pattern.
- `!d` deletes all lines except those corresponding to the range.
- `//d` matches the same pattern as the address(es) and removes it.

Comment: Thanks, that works - how would I read "Heading 2" as an argument to the bash script? I tried replacing it with `$1`, but I got no output.

Comment: @Dov Variables are expanded inside double-quoted strings, not single-quoted strings.

Comment: I need to make some adjustments - would you be able to give a breakdown of what each part of your `sed` expression is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
head2="$(sed -n '/## Heading 2/,/## Heading 3/{s/^## Heading .*//;p;}' file)"

echo "$head2"


* List item 1
* List item 2
```

Using `perl`:

```
head2="$(perl -0pe 's/(?s).*## Heading 2\s*(.*)\s*## Heading 3.*/\1/' file)"

echo "$head2"
* List item 1
* List item 2
```

You can also install **gnu** `grep` using `home brew` and use this regex:

```
head2="$(grep -zoP '## Heading 2\s*\K[\s\S]*(?=\s*## Heading 3)' file)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` ranges:

```
awk '/^## Heading 2/,/^## Heading [^2]/ {if (!/^## Heading 2/&&!/^## Heading [^2]/) { print}}'
```

or with variables

```
awk '/s/,/e/ {if ($0 !~ s && $0 !~ e) { print}}' s='^## Heading 2' e='^## Heading [^2]'
```